# setState using regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I used computed way to set my state like

```
this.setState({ chat-[`${id}`]: some_id })
```

But the problem is I don't have the id to set it to false, can I do regex with setState? I want to set chat-* to false in componentWillMount.

Comment: So you want to set all properties starting with `chat-` to the same thing?

Comment: @Aron correct, set it to false.

Comment: why not make an array ? then when you need to update specific state you can just `this.state.chat[index] = newValue` after that just assign the state again `this.setState({ chat })`

Comment: If you're going to have an arbitrary number of variables stored in state I think you'll want to store it differently, either as an array or as an object where the `id`s are the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do it for you:

```
// newState obj     
let newState = {};

// iterate over object keys, finding matching 'chat-*' keys
Object.keys(this.state).forEach((key) => {
   if (key.startsWith('chat-')) {
    newState[key] = false; // set it to false
  }
});

this.setState(newState);  // update state
```

Note that your newState is automatically merged to the old state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: this will override my other existing state

Comment: State updates are merged, you don't need to worry about other parts of your state: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Answer (score 0):

You could have a loop update the state object and then set back the state like

```
 handleClick() {
           var obj = {...this.state};
           for(var key in obj) {
              if(/count-*/g.test(key))
                  obj[key] = 1;
           }
           console.log(obj)
           this.setState({...obj})
        }
```

Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
          'count-0': 0,
          'count-1': 0
        }
        handleClick() {
           var obj = {...this.state};
           for(var key in obj) {
              if(/count-*/g.test(key))
                  obj[key] = 1;
           }
           console.log(obj)
           this.setState({...obj})
        }
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state['count-0']}</div>
                <div>{this.state['count-1']}</div>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()} >Increase</button>
            </div>
          )
        }
       
    }
    

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
```